# When to call asynchronous QMenu::popup() vs synchronous QMenu::exec()?

Tags: qt, qt5

[Reading the Qt5 source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qlabel.cpp#n921), I noticed that `QLabel::contextMenuEvent()` uses this (non-blocking) style:

```
QMenu *menu = ...
menu->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
// Non-blocking
menu->popup(event->globalPos());
```

Alternatively, I have seen this (blocking) style from Qt code samples:

```
QMenu *menu = ...
// Blocking
QAction* action = menu->exec(event->globalPos());
// Or before menu->exec() call: menu->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose)
delete menu;
```

I can see these differences:

- Non-blocking vs blocking
- Return `void` vs `QAction*`

Are their other differences?  Example: Is there an *advantage* to non-blocking, e.g., the event loop can process other events?  If the difference is purely style, please let me know.

Finally, I do notice that debugging the non-blocking style is a little bit weird for me on GNU/Linux/KDE, but that might be unrelated.

Comment: The main differences are described here:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/21099/solved-what-s-the-difference-between-qmenu-popup-and-qmenu-exec_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When to call QMenu::popup() vs QMenu::exec()?

The former: Always. The latter: Never. It's that easy.

Why? Because re-entering event loops leads to spaghetti code. The world as asynchronous and you can't pretend that you're "waiting" for something in synchronous-looking code while the world goes on and does all sorts of things that this code style hides from you. The `exec()` call really means "run arbitrary parts of my application, until an indeterminate time when the user decides they have had enough of the popup". If it sounds nasty, then it's meant to: it's nasty, buggy, terrible way to develop UI code, and leads to bugs that are hard to debug, and allows you to procrastinate instead of spending time actually doing it in the asynchronous fashion. I am appalled that the Qt Project still provides this in their code examples. `exec()` is bannable. There are very few cases where it has to be used due to broken Qt's platform-specific code. E.g. Qt didn't bother (last time I checked) to implement `QDrag` support from the main runloop on MacOS, so they spin up a local one just because Apple's example code shows the same idiocy, whereas it can be done without AFAIK (although it's nbot as trivial - but so what, it's library code, it's not supposed to be always trivial - otherwise the users could do it themselves).

You can use a state machine (`QStateMachine`) to specify the behavior of your application, having a dedicated state for when the particular popup is visible, and then you can do the necessary responses as the application exits that state. You can also write Qt ui code using C++20 coroutines, with some scaffolding code to allow that (Qt doesn't provide any yet).

Comment: I write this comment with real honesty and respect: I had to read your answer _several_ times before I could get my head around what you wrote!  At first, I thought your response contained a typo between sync `exec()` and async `popup()`.  Later, I realised you were saying that sync `exec()` is actually *hiding* things from the developer!  I have been writing GUIs as a very average dev for 20 years and never once did I think about this idea.  Thank you to open the door!

Comment: It appears that @scopchanov is recommending exactly the opposite.  Could you please comment?  I value your opinion.

Comment: @kevinarpe, KubaOber is extremely experienced and I highly value his opinion. I suggest you to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @scopchanov Oh, I may be extremely experienced in doing things the wrong way, too :) But generally anything that plasters around the asynchronous nature of most interactive or even network applications is asking for big trouble - I've ran into it so many times that I am conditioned to react strongly, since it never, not once, ends well. This should become much easier to deal with once Qt supports modern C++ asynchronous code (`co_await` and friends). That'll allow writing straight-line code with well defined async behaviors and no thread blocking while waiting.

Answer (score 1):

I could add the following to your observations:

Taking look at the source code of [`QMenu::exec`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qmenu.cpp.html#_ZN5QMenu4execERK6QPointP7QAction), it becomes clear, that this method is, so to say, superior to `QMenu::popup`, meaning that it extends its functionality, namely by adding an event loop:

```
QAction *QMenu::exec(const QPoint &p, QAction *action)
{
    ...
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    d->eventLoop = &eventLoop;
    popup(p, action);
    ...
    (void) eventLoop.exec();
    ...
    d->eventLoop = nullptr;
    return action;
}
```

Effectively this makes handling an `exec`-uted `QMenu` more like a `QDialog` (meaning that it is modal and you get the result directly as a returned value), while a `popup`-ed one, more like a regular `QWidget`, with the result obtained through signals and slots. You might of course call this a matter of programming style, but depending on the application, the more low-level access of `QMenu::popup` compared to `QMenu::exec` might be a better fit.

Comment: Sorry for my very late reply.  It appears that @UnslanderMonica is recommending exactly the opposite. Could you please comment? I value your opinion.

Comment: @kevinarpe, I do not think it is exactly the opposite. I do not claim `exec` is better.  I have used the words _might be_ and _depending on the situation_. My answer is valid, because it shows facts from the source code. There is little to none analisys going on. KubaOber's answer on the other hand is focused on the analysis. I do not think there is a conflict. In any case, I like his answer more and I suggest you to accept it.

Comment: @kevinarpe Just to clarify - `superior` does not mean better. It means that it extends the functionality of `popup`, i.e. does more things.