# QDialog.exec() vs open()

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qdialog

The docs for QDialog suggest avoiding `exec()` in favor of `open()` because of possible bugs that can be introduced when exec() is used. `open()` doesn't block, so you need to catch a signal like `finished()` to detect that the dialog has been closed. If the dialog is capturing values (eg, text edit or combo box), you must have access to the QDialog object in order to fetch the values. Since you can't pass this to the function connected to the `finished()` signal, the variable must have scope that includes this function. Not the end of the world, but the `exec()` approach doesn't require catching the `finished()` signal and defining another function - you're still in the scope of the QDialog object that was `exec()`ed, so you can immediately access the desired values.

All of this leads to the question, how bad is it to use `exec()` instead of `open()`? I looked at the code for QGetOpenFileName to see how it was able to display a dialog and return a value, and it uses `exec()`, so clearly it's not the end of the world. Are there precautions one can take to avoid the downsides of this choice?

Comment: That is a general suggestion, that has to be considered for safety. The most "bad" thing that can happen is that the parent gets deleted while the dialog is still open (and that's bad indeed). In most situations, using `exec()` is completely fine, you only have to be very careful when the program is *very* complex and there are other things happening in the main event loop, including possible threads that might do something "dangerous" for the dialog.

Comment: @musicamante I don't get it. Why is deleting the parent "bad/dangerous"? I just created a simple example which used `sip.delete` to nuke the parent and nothing unexpected happened. The dialog simply remains on screen and the program terminates normally when it's closed. Of course, if I try to delete the parent again, a runtime-error will be raised - but so what? That's just a programming error. I strongly doubt that it's possible to come up with a *non-contrived* "dangerous" example that employs commonplace usage of `exec()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to call asynchronous QMenu::popup() vs synchronous QMenu::exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303201/when-to-call-asynchronous-qmenupopup-vs-synchronous-qmenuexec)

Comment: Take a look at Kuba Ober's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63714735/5366641

Comment: @scopchanov That looks like a lot of strongly worded assertions without any supporting evidence or examples. Presumably, the author of the accepted answer would also argue that the static methods of `QMessageBox`, `QFileDialog`, `QInputDialog`, etc are all abominations that we would be better off without?

Comment: @ekhumoro, in my opinion the appropriate place for your comment is under the aforementioned post itself. That way you would be able to reach its author directly. You might also consider writing a separate answer if you think, that there is something more, which is worth mentioning. In any case, I believe that the duplicated question should be closed.

Comment: @scopchanov The OP rightly asks why it's okay for built-in functions like `getOpenFileName` to use `exec`, but not user code. Your suggested duplicate question does not provide any useful advice regarding that, because it's about `QMenu`, not `QDialog`. Your linked answer states that there's *never* any reason for using `exec` - that may be arguable for `QMenu`, but it's clearly false for `QDialog`. Also, like the [Qt Docs for exec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec), it hints at potential bugs, but does not offer any concrete examples. Thus, it doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @ekhumoro right, I didn't consider that deleting the parent should (?) cause the child dialog to exit its event loop and delete that too. But, besides that, I've already seen other complaints and preoccupations about `exec`, like in this bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-73287

Comment: @musicamante Thanks. The proper explanation is found in this Qt Blog post: [Unpredictable exec()](https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/02/23/unpredictable-exec); and in this Qt Quarterly 30 article: [New Ways of Using Dialogs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/QtQuarterly30.pdf). Most of the problems seem to stem from coding style, program design and a few platform/language related issues - all of which are avoidable, but perhaps easy to miss if you're not aware of the potential pifalls. The Qt docs could certainly do a better job of explaining how these problems might arise.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank *you*, those links provide interesting and useful insights. And I agree, the documentation should explain those aspects more carefully, especially considering that the problem first arised more than 10 years ago, the QTBUG I linked is almost 3 years old, and Qt6 still has the same identical note (which, as you pointed out, doesn't seem to be a problem - but maybe it might be in complex situations?). Anywho, those are really important aspects one should always be made aware of, and they also explain some odd behavior I sometimes faced in the past.