# How to Import Pyqt5 Widget In Another File

Tags: python, pyqt5

First File first.py

```
import pyqt5py

ret=pyqt5py.confirm()
print(ret)
```

Second File Having PYQT5 name: pyqt5py.py

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic


class Ui(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self,button1='Ok',button2='Cancel',text='Are You Sure?'):
        super(Ui, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('dialog.ui', self) # Load the .ui file
        # Show the GUI
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.click(1))
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.click(2))
        self.label.setText(text)
        self.pushButton1.setText(button1)
        self.pushButton2.setText(button2)
        self.show()
    def click(self,args):
        print(self)
        return self.sender().text()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) # Create an instance of QtWidgets.QApplication
def confirm():
    def pressed():
        return 'clicked'
    window = Ui(button1='Ok',button2='Cancel',text='Are You Sure?') # Create an instance of our class
    print(window)
    window.pushButton1.clicked.connect(pressed)
    app.exec_() # Start the application
```

but i dont know what changes should i do make my first.py to work,i have correctly made the pyqt5 file but i dont know how to add def to call it for confirm

#######################
I Updated My Second File

Comment: Hi. What kind of behaviour do you expect?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you are trying to create your own dialog that you can call from another file. In that case, you should modify `pyqt5py.py` so that the creation of QApplication is only done for testing. You can accomplish this by putting the last three lines inside a `if __name__=='main'` statement. `first.py` needs to create it's own QApplication. Also you never create an instance of Ui in `first.py`.

Comment: I Updated Code of second file having pyqt5,But Its Not Returning clicked,Pls Tell Me How To Fix It, and thanks for reply and help

Comment: I am afraid it is still not clear what you expect. What do you want to happen in first.py? Also, you call ```confirm()``` with the argument ```hello```, but your function definition does not expect any argument. And why do you need ```def pressed():``` at all and especially as a nested function within ```confirmed()```?

Comment: i am expecting that i made yes or cancel dialog box , i wanna use it with jarvis(ai) program by importing the dialog box and i want to know wheteher user wants to shutdown computer or not? so please help me 
if u still not clear i will tell an example that i want to recreate
like pyautogui.confirm() 
i want to create above pyautogui.confirm() by me with custom design dialog box so please help me please

Comment: Anyone pls reply please please

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [bfris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9705687/bfris) you should rewrite the last lines of pyqt5py.py as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    window = Ui(button1='Ok',button2='Cancel',text='Are You Sure?')
    app.exec_()
```

That way you can run this file directly for debbugging purposes, but also import it elsewhere.

To use your widget in first.py you need to create an instance of it there.

first.py:

```
from pyqt5py.py import UI

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
window = Ui(button1='Ok',button2='Cancel',text='Are You Sure?')
app.exec_()
```

Usually I use a QDialog within a Qt environment where it is opened from a QMainWindow and also returning which button was clicked to the QMainWindow.
However as I understand you would like to run another program and in between open your UI? I am not experienced doing that but it seems to me that its [exec method](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjH_-6grPj6AhXmhM4BHe3lBPIQFnoECBgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdoc.qt.io%2Fqtforpython-5%2FPySide2%2FQtWidgets%2FQDialog.html&usg=AOvVaw0wDDeG3ah1d8Fhvt1joCHT) does exactly that though you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037311/qdialog-exec-vs-open) discussion about a bug related to it.
Alternatively in first.py you connect the pushbutton's clicked signal to a slot, a function there.